# html/php: Changing images order by swapping filenames doesn't take immediate effect

Tags: php, varnish

I have following problem that's bugging my mind completely. I have to take over this cms from someone who doesn't want to care for it anymore and is giving no support whatsoever. 
Situation is as follows: on the site there are several photo albums which are populated by reading a directory in php. All is good there, pictures are shown in the order they are read. In the management system, these pictures can be changed in order by an up or down-button. The way this is done is by swapping the image's filenames. This works, when I change the order for an image i can see server-side the filenames have actually been swapped.
This is however not the case on the site, at least not immediately: it takes an average of 10 minutes to see the images swapped there. Ofcourse, my client can't work like this, and he claims it has always worked before. I have tried to turn off caching browser-side, this hasn't helped. I can also note the changes take effect on the same time in IE and FF. I tried several ways of turning off cache server-side in php too, also to no avail.
Is there any other place where I should be looking or could there be another reason why these changes don't take effect immediately?

In addition, changes i make to javascript don't get picked up immediately too. I installed fiddler and this is the request header for that js file:

GET http://www.nobel-country-gite.be/admin/modules/Photoalbum/js/album.js HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/javascript, */*;q=0.8
Referer: http://www.nobel-country-gite.be/admin/index.php?page=pic&album=24
Accept-Language: nl-BE
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
If-Modified-Since: Wed, 27 May 2015 15:55:12 GMT
If-None-Match: "ba1248f5-138b-5171244a92f66"
DNT: 1
Host: www.nobel-country-gite.be
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: __utmc=39679548; __utma=39679548.1608184058.1429963360.1432662247.1432664636.7; __utmz=39679548.1429963360.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmc=1; PHPSESSID=7uge1ltg2rc11q63untthrc5s1; __utma=1.459796341.1429963360.1432662247.1432664636.7; __utmz=1.1429963360.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)

Response header is as follows:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Wed, 27 May 2015 15:55:12 GMT
ETag: "ba1248f5-138b-5171244a92f66"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: application/javascript
Date: Wed, 27 May 2015 16:57:55 GMT
X-Varnish: 1826689067 1825041752
Age: 556
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive

I would expect the answer to be different instead of 'not modified'?

Edit - upon waiting a few minutes and refreshing the page again, the response for this file is what is expected:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Wed, 27 May 2015 16:57:30 GMT
ETag: "ba1248f5-1387-51713237ac28e"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: application/javascript
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 27 May 2015 17:03:43 GMT
X-Varnish: 1827728442
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: What CMS are you using?

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly... You have an image-ordering webpage where a user can reorder images to their liking. This swaps the image names server-side (so as an example, server-side the name scheme is image_1, image_2 etc., the user swaps image_1 with image_2 and image_2 is now renamed to image_1 and image_1 is renamed to image_2) and then you refresh the webpage or (if you're awesome) you're using AJAX, and upon content refresh, the images are still in the order they were in before the renaming took place (image_2 is still image_2 and image_1 is still image_1)?

Comment: Aside from PHP and the browser, caching can be enabled in your webserver (e.g. Apache). Check the rendered HTML to see whether the browser is remembering old image content or the server is sending the old file order.Get [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and observe: are the requests actually being sent to the server? Are their responses up-to-date? Do the responses have any cache headers?

Comment: Isn't there a cache option in the CMS ?

Comment: Dan - A custom made cms
ctwheels - Indeed, that is the case. It takes several minutes for the images to be actually swapped on the site, but on the serve i do see the changes immediately
DCoder - I will try to get more information through Fiddler
Hakim - No, there seems to be no option there

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't help but notice you are using [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) (indicated by the X-Varnish response header).  Varnish is a caching reverse proxy, which means your pages are not just being cached by the browser, but also on the server (by Varnish).  Your browser connects to Varnish, and Varnish connects to your Apache backend.

The first response header includes "Age: 556" - that's the cached version's age in seconds (almost 10 minutes).  Then the age comes across as "0" when the page refreshes - that's because Varnish has updated its cache.  Probably you can access the page over HTTPS to see your changes immediately reflected (Varnish doesn't work for HTTPS and most people don't bother setting up an HTTPS cache), or you can generally add garbage GET parameters to your URL (e.g. "?bogus=123") to force Varnish to re-fetch the page (this won't make other users see the new version, since they'll be accessing via the normal URLs).

Fixes: You can use `varnishadm` to ban (expire) certain URLs in Varnish when you've made a change; you can modify the "Cache-Control" or "Expires" headers your CMS/Apache (via PHP, .htaccess, etc.) produces to reduce cache time (Varnish completely respects cache control headers in its caching strategy); you can change Varnish's behavior by editing the relevant VCL (usually "default.vcl"); or you can accept that caches are generally good (they save a lot of time and resources in generating the response), and maybe a 10 minute delay is an acceptable trade-off.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I just talked to one.com's support team and they told me to add a header to my htaccess-file to disable this varnish-header. This seems to be working, changes take immediate effect now. Is there anything I need to be aware of when disabling this cache?

Comment: I'm glad the answer helped! Please mark it as Accepted so others with similar questions can find useful resources. In answer to your comment: Without Varnish, your Apache backend will be handling a greatly increased load, and so will your PHP and any relevant databases. This may result in service interruption - you'll want to make sure your Apache instance can handle sufficient concurrent connections, etc. And it'll be slower. Generally, Varnish is a very, very good thing. I would not disable it without a very compelling argument. It'd be better to use varnishadm to expire the cache as needed.

Comment: Unfortunately the way the cms is written doesn't allow me to do that. If a user wishes to change the order of those images he should be able to see this immediately on his admin-page. If I write such a cms myself, I store the order in a database, in this particular cms they've done it by swapping the image filenames.

Comment: If the admin user himself wants to see the change immediately he can simply add dummy parameters to his URL. If that's difficult, you can easily create a bookmarklet that does this in one click. Editors are surprisingly trainable. In the worst case, edit the Varnish VCL or use .htaccess to set a short cache life *only on the relevant page* so that Varnish can still cache all of the other pages. What Varnish provides should really not be dismissed readily.

Comment: Another solution is to have Varnish bypass cache if a given COOKIE is set, and then set that COOKIE for all of your editors, or bypass cache for a given IP address range. Either way, any editor will always see the live version, but the big public Internet won't be causing unnecessary load.